# Pivot table concept

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my table input

```
Name      Occupation
----------------------
Ashley    Professor 

Samantha  Actor 

Julia     Doctor 

Britney   Professor 

Maria     Professor 

Meera     Professor 

Priya     Doctor 

Priyanka  Professor 

Jennifer  Actor

Ketty Actor 
.
.
.

Christeen Singer 

Eve Actor 

Aamina Doctor
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Doctor   Professsor singer     Actor
-----------------------------------------------
Aamina   Ashley   Christeen    Eve 

Julia   Belvet   Jane          Jennifer

Priya   Britney  Jenny         Ketty 

NULL    Maria    Kristeen      Samantha

NULL    Meera    NULL          NULL 

NULL    Naomi    NULL          NULL
```

IN output header should not display i.e. doctor,singer,...
This is my question i can do it by using Case statement. But the script took to long. So someone help to dispaly the output using Pivot concept in sql server

Comment: Add the SQL you tried to your question.

Comment: Yes i have tried but I don’t know how to use pivot concept. Even i have search in google and YouTube there is no perfect example for Getting output without headers

Comment: You mentioned you have tried a script. Add that to your question, even if incorrect, so that we can better help you.

Comment: Yes i will past my query .The output is correct but i want to use a pivot concept

Comment: Actually, you can't use pivot for your situation, you should aggregate something to use it.

Comment: Okie thanks for everyone one @rainman and@dan guzman

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this is what you are wanting. I used 4 common table expressions (CTE) to get the names of each profession. I have a windows function in each CTE to order the names and assign an `Id` to each name. I join all the CTE's by the `Id` and you have your results.

```
WITH doctor AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Occupation 
                    ORDER BY [Name]) AS Id,[Name],Occupation
FROM your_Table
WHERE Occupation = 'Doctor'),

professor AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Occupation 
                    ORDER BY [Name]) AS Id,[Name],Occupation
FROM your_Table
WHERE Occupation = 'Professor'),

singer AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Occupation 
                    ORDER BY [Name]) AS Id,[Name],Occupation
FROM your_Table
WHERE Occupation = 'Singer'),

actor AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Occupation 
                    ORDER BY [Name]) AS Id,[Name],Occupation
FROM your_Table
WHERE Occupation = 'Actor')

SELECT d.Name AS 'Doctor',p.Name AS 'Professor',
        s.Name AS 'Singer',a.Name AS 'Actor'
FROM doctor d
     FULL OUTER JOIN professor p ON d.Id = p.Id
     FULL OUTER JOIN singer s ON p.Id = s.Id
     FULL OUTER JOIN actor a ON s.Id = a.Id
```

Results:

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| Doctor | Professor |  Singer   |  Actor   |
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| Aamina | Ashley    | Christeen | Eve      |
| Julia  | Belvet    | Jane      | Jennifer |
| Priya  | Britney   | Jenny     | Ketty    |
| NULL   | Maria     | Kristeen  | Samantha |
| NULL   | Meera     | NULL      | NULL     |
| NULL   | Naomi     | NULL      | NULL     |
| NULL   | Priyanka  | NULL      | NULL     |
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```